# Is it possible to develop mobile app using jhipster?

Tags: java, android, ios, spring-boot, jhipster

i have not enough knowledge about jhipster that's why today one question on my mind.

Is it possible to create android/ios mobile application using jhipster ?

Comment: User asked question in small text but his question is clear to me, It can't be categorized as broad and don't downgrade the question.

Comment: His question is very clear and useful for me, thanks

Comment: i had same question. as i understand it it is posible with nativescript but that is not in jhipster

Comment: here is a tutorial how you could do it with cordova: https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could create java backend server with JHipster and create the mobile app using [ignite-jhipster](https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster) in React Native or using [generator-jhipster-ionic](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic) in Ionic.